# Any clue why my images keep cutting off? (sprites)

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I've put all the tiny blue logo images as sprites for my client's site, but they keep getting cut off in certain browsers... Try shrinking your browser window and you'll see that part of some of the images just disappear. I have no idea why this is happening. Here's some sample code of the HTML.

```
<div class="fourCol">
<div id="firstSecond" class="centerContent" style="width:48px;height:48px;">
<img class="agenda" src="images/trans.png"  alt="agenda">
</div>
</div>
```

The sprite is just the standard method of "spriting" in CSS...

Here's the url: [front page](http://compactcourse.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your css  in

```
media="all" @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)
.responsive-grid-active .block img{
height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is overriding your image height:

```
.responsive-grid-active .block img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto
}
```

in responseive-grid-39b007c.css

remove the height: auto line and it doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: oh, okay. so if i put the css in the stylesheet instead of inline, it should work fine?

Comment: Abdul's answer is better.  Just override it in your style sheet.